# How to send the data from HPA to external API service

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, autoscaling, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am currently working in dynamic scaling of services with custom metrics and I wanted to send some data **from HPA to my external API service**. Is there any way or any post request which will send the *current replica count* to my external API ?
Like HPA has its sync period and it sends GET request to API to fetch the metric value so is there any way to also have some POST request so that I can get some data from HPA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't per se, your service can watch the Kubernetes API for updates like everything else though. All components in Kubernetes communicate through the API.

Comment: kubectl get --raw /api/v1/namespaces/myNamespace/pods
you mean something like this ? ,this will give all the data in json format but I just want specific value that is number of pods of specific deployment ... what I should do ?

Comment: You will have to pull it out of the JSON. And you'll probably want to use a Watch request so you get streaming updates. We have clients in most major languages (Go, Python, Java, JS, Rust, probably more). Use one of those.

Comment: sure thank you ! can I have a link for the same ?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: i am using java

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java or https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client